# Launch application when GCM notification received

Tags: android, android-intent, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I have GCM notification implementation. I know that the client application receives the notification whether it is in the foreground, background or killed state. What I would like to know is, how can I launch my application on notification received, when the application is in the killed state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the message receiver, I do the following:

```
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Here replace YourActivity.class with the entry activity. This worked for me.

Comment: What if app is removed from task list? in that case "message receiver" will not called. It will handle by system and it clicked by "click_action" tag. But my concern is open my target activity after notification arrived.

Comment: how to get context here in fcm message ??

Answer (score 2):

you Can Use NotificationManager to Start your activity.

try to use Below Code Inside your **onMessage()** method Which is overridden method in Class that extends **GCMBaseIntentService** class of GCM.

```
int icon = R.drawable.your_app_icon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // notificationIntent.putExtra("PostName", vPostText);
        // Log.i(TAG, "Sent Postid " + postid);

        // Util util = (Util) context.getApplicationContext();
        // util.setPostID(postid);
        // util.setNotify(true);
        // util.setUserNAME(vPortCode);
        // util.setPostNAME(vPostText);
        // util.setmEDIA(vMedia);
        // util.setmEDIATHHUMB(vMediaThumb);
        // util.setmEDIATYPE(vMediaType);
        // util.setAirportName(vAirportName);

        notificationIntent.putExtra("Set_image", true);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Notify", true);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        // notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                (int) System.nanoTime(), notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify((int) System.nanoTime(), notification);
```

Comment: Thank you.I know how to start an activity from the application. But, What I would like to do is,on notification received,if my application is in the background,i would bring it to the fore ground, 
if it is in the foreground then i would continue processing, and if my application is in the stop/killed state then i want to "relaunch the application" not activity.
So can you tell me if there is any way to launch the application when the application is in the stop/killed state on notification received?

Comment: @jasdmystery: did you find away out? i'm facing same issue.

Comment: Refer to the answer above.